# Multiple query search in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, search

I try to get search result on multiple input and make statements to get or ignore any of inputs in case that user didn't set any value for some of inputs.

## Logic

User will:

1. Select `category`
2. Select `Subcategory` of that `category`
3. Select `Specification` or `brand` or `both` from `products` in that
   subcategory

What I've done so far is getting all the info from logic above, ***what I need is function for search from that data***.

## codes

`Form`

```
<form action="{{route('finderfunction')}}" class="mt-20">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="category_id">category</label>
                    <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->title}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div><!-- end col-md-3 -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="subcategory_id">subcategory</label>
                    <select name="subcategory_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- end col-md-3 -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="specification_id">specifications</label>
                    <select name="specification_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Specification</option>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- end col-md-3 -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="brand_id">brands</label>
                    <select name="brand_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Brand</option>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- end col-md-3 -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                        <button style="margin: 20px;" class="pull-right btn btn-info" type="submit">Find</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

`JavaScript`

```
<!-- get subcategories -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="category_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var categoryID = $(this).val();
      if(categoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getSubCategories') }}/'+encodeURI(categoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').append('<option value="'+ value['id'] +'">'+ value['title'] +'</option>');
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- get specifications -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getspecifications') }}/'+encodeURI(subcategoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                  $('select[name="specification_id"]').append(
                        "<option class='form-control' value='"+ value['id'] +"'>"+ value['title'] +"</option>");
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- get brands -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getbrands') }}/'+encodeURI(subcategoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="brand_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="brand_id"]').append('<option class="form-control" value="'+ value['id'] +'">'+ value['title'] +'</option>');
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="brand_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: screen1]

`Search function`

Unfortunately I do not have any function for search in this data, `that's why I asked here` **need help to make it**

```
public function finderfunction(Request $request) {
        //
}
```

`route`

```
Route::any('/finder', 'frontend\SearchController@finderfunction')->name('finderfunction');
```

Comment: You can use a clean solution shown in this couple of laracast: [This one](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/14) and in [the consecutive one](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/15).

Comment: I put it here cause I'm really tired RN to help you with your code, but those videos are really clear. Is nice the way Jeff use those Filter classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$post = $request->all(); //Initialize the request
$test = DB::table('products')
->where('subcategory_id','=',$post['subcategory_id']);

if(isset($post['specification_id']) && !(isset($post['brand_id'])))
{
$test= $test->where('subspecification_id','=',$post['specification_id']);
}
elseif(!(isset($post['specification_id'])) && isset($post['brand_id']))
{
$test= $test->where('brand_id','=',$post['brand_id']);
}
else
{
$test= $test->where('subspecification_id','=',$post['specification_id'])
->where('brand_id','=',$post['brand_id']);
}

$test = $test->get();
```

Comment: not sure why, but your first answer return some data, this one no!

Comment: my bad i missed some terminations. i've edited it again :D

Comment: Undefined variable: query

Comment: did you declare the query like i did in the third line underneath the declaration of post variable?

Comment: you mean this? `$query = ` if so then yes i did

Comment: sure. wait i upload it somewhere give you the link

Comment: it appears to be empty :O

Comment: :| ok i make gist

Comment: saw your error on the line of if else. you must retain the $test variable that you use. i've editted my answer again based on your code

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654236/multiple-query-search-in-laravel/48654465?noredirect=1#comment84308091_48654747

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
return DB::table('products')
        ->where(function($query) use ($request){
          if($request->has('category')){
                        $query->where('category','=',$request->category);
                    }
                    if($request->has('subcategory')){
                        $query->where('subcategory','=',$request->subcategory);
                    }
                 })
                 ->where(function($query) use($request){
                    if($request->has('specifications') && $request->has('brands')){
                        $query->where('specifications','=',$request->specifications)->where('brands','=',$request->brands); // comes specifications and brand
                    }
                    if($request->has('specifications')){
                        $query->orWhere('specifications','=',$request->specifications);
                    }
                    if($request->has('brands')){
                        $query->orWhere('brands','=',$request->brands);
                    }
                 })->get();
```

Comment: `return ` at the first? are you sure?

Comment: Undefined variable: query

Comment: your `function($query)` closes before `->where(function() use($request){` how can other `query` be defined?

Comment: seems to me it's working but wait till i check it completely.

Comment: I have issue here, about `specifications` the thing is for subcategory and brands i get their id in products table because only use 1 id and that's it, but for specifications I'm using 3rd table named `product_subspecification` now when I use your method it return data base on `subcategory` and `brands` but will not return base on `specifications` because it's looking into products table for it while it has to look in my `product_subspecification` table. in next comment i'll share my query how did i get those data in first place.

Comment: `$specifications = DB::table('products')
               ->where('subcategory_id', $id)
               ->join('product_subspecification', 'product_subspecification.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
               ->join('subspecifications', 'subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
               ->groupBy('subspecifications.id')
               ->get();
         return response()->json($specifications);`  here is how i got my subspecifications under selected subcategory only. in search query we should make this happen again i guess.